# Difference of two uncorrelated random variable variances

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance

so I have this problem:

```
Y1 and Y2 are uncorrelated discrete random variables
Var[2Y1-Y2]= 17
Var[Y1+2Y2]= 5
What is Var[Y1-Y2]
Hint: What is Var[aY2 + bY2] in terms of Var[Y1]and Var[Y2] when Y1 and Y2 are uncorrelated?
```

I'm unsure of what to make of the hint, but could someone explain how to utilize the hint ot solve the problem? I'm quite lost

Comment: I’ll assume there’s a typo in the hint and that it’s supposed to be Var[aY1+bY2] instead of Var[aY2+bY2].  You can use the fact that Var[aY1+bY2] = (a^2)Var[Y1]+(b^2)Var[Y2]+2abCov[Y1,Y2], but when Y1 and Y2 are uncorrelated, Cov[Y1,Y2]=0.

Using the above relationship, you can get two equations of Var[Y1] and Var[Y2] and solve for each of them. Also, in order to get your signs correct, it may be helpful to think of 2Y1-Y2 as 2Y1+(-1)Y2 and Y1-Y2 as Y1+(-1)Y2.

Comment: Hint: $Y_1-Y_2 = (3/5)(2Y_1-Y_2) - (1/5)(Y_1+2Y_2).$ Apply the hint to the question of finding the variance of $(3/5)X_1 + (-1/5)X_2$ where $X_1=2Y_1-Y2$ and $X_2=Y_1+2Y_2$. It might also be instructional to ponder the assumption that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are discrete: where is that information needed?